# How to stop a session in Google mobile analytics v2 for android without EasyTracker

Tags: android, analytics

I've read the documentation on the GoogleAnalytics v2 website (I've basically read all the pages from https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/) but was not able to find an accurate enough to answer my question. It is either missing or mixed with the version 1 documentation.

I know that with EasyTracker, you can set a timeout_session parameter. But I dont want to use EasyTracker and I want to explicitly stop a session at some point in my code. (not setting a timeout)

I start a session when I open my application with :

```
mTracker.setStartSession(true);
```

and was wondering if calling

```
mTracker.setStartSession(false);
```

explicitely stops it.

Any help or point to a better tutorial/documentation would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the GA v3, to manually start or end a session, use the tracker's session control parameter as follows:

Start a new session. The next hit from this tracker will be the first in a new session.

```
[tracker set:kGAISessionControl value:@"start"];
```

End a session. The next hit from this tracker will be the last in the current session.

```
[tracker set:kGAISessionControl value:@"end"];
```

This information is available from the link:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/sessions

Comment: Hi,
thank you for that ! I was asking for android (i've put the tag "Android" to my question) so here is a link more appropriate to my question : https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v3/sessions
It is the same as yours but for Android...
Also I was asking for analytics v2 but I guess I'll have to migrate to v3 then. I accept your answer as I think it is the more accurate.
Thanks again.

Answer (score 6):

**Overview**

So I spent some time going through the [Measurement Protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/) as well as looking through the debug logs in LogCat.  When GA on your phone 'dispatches' a bunch of hits, every hit seems to have a corresponding HTTP request in the log that begins with:

```
GET /collect?...
```

and is followed by a bunch of [parameters](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters) that define the type of hit (e.g. event, social, e-commerce) and some basic info about the app (e.g. app id, tracking id, timestamp).

Here's what I learned:

`setStartSession(false)` does *not* end a session.

---

**How I Discovered It**

As I said earlier, every hit represents some type of an action.  However, session starts or session ends are not considered hits.  They are merely additional data that is added on to the *most recent hit* that tell GA to group the future hits in a new session.

So if you `sendEvent(...)` and then `setStartSession(true)`, and then `dispatch()`, you'll see ONE hit in the logs that describes the event *with* an additional parameter `&sc=start` that describes the starting of a new session.

I then tried doing the above using `setStartSession(false)` and I did not notice the additional `&sc` parameter.  It should have been `&sc=end`, as described [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#session).

---

**Potential Hack**

The tracker had a `send(...)` method that seems like it would allow you to send a custom hit by specifying the necessary parameters.  After some trial and error, the following successfully created an event *and* attached the session ending parameter as described above.

```
Map<String, String> data;
data = EasyTracker.getTracker().constructEvent("Test", "Test", "Test", 0L);
data.put("sessionControl", "end");
EasyTracker.getTracker().send("event", data);
```

So theoretically, every time you want to end a session, you could a dummy event (like above), add the `sessionControl` parameter, and dispatch.  From the logs it seems to work perfectly, but I haven't verified this on my GA dashboard.

And make sure you disable automatic session control by setting `ga_sessionTimeout` to `-1` in your `analytics.xml` file.

I also uploaded [my project here](https://github.com/gautamjain/GA-session-test), if you want to try looking through the logs and comparing the hits.  Make sure you update your GA tracking id.  Hope this helps!

[image]

---

**My Logs**

Start Session + Test Event, Dispatch

```
GET /collect?ul=en-us&ev=0&ht=1362779137510&sr=720x1184&a=0&sc=start&aid=com.example.com.example.sessiontest&ea=Test&cid=ae57a272-89b2-46ab-8c82-7acdb49c3669&ec=Test&av=1.0&v=1&t=event&el=Test&an=com.example.sessiontest&tid=UA-XXXXXXXX-X&_u=.sMC&_v=ma1b4&cd=com.example.com.example.sessiontest.MainActivity&qt=2788&z=48 HTTP/1.1
```

End Session + Test Event, Dispatch

```
GET /collect?ul=en-us&ev=0&ht=1362779233499&sr=720x1184&a=0&aid=com.example.com.example.sessiontest&ea=Test&cid=ae57a272-89b2-46ab-8c82-7acdb49c3669&ec=Test&av=1.0&v=1&t=event&el=Test&an=com.example.sessiontest&tid=UA-XXXXXXXX-X&_u=.ssMMC&_v=ma1b4&cd=com.example.com.example.sessiontest.MainActivity&qt=3726&z=50 HTTP/1.1
```

End Session Hack + Test Event, Dispatch

```
GET /collect?ul=en-us&ev=0&ht=1362779194381&sr=720x1184&a=0&sc=end&aid=com.example.com.example.sessiontest&ea=Test&cid=ae57a272-89b2-46ab-8c82-7acdb49c3669&ec=Test&av=1.0&v=1&t=event&el=Test&an=com.example.sessiontest&tid=UA-XXXXXXXX-X&_u=.ssyL&_v=ma1b4&cd=com.example.com.example.sessiontest.MainActivity&qt=3581&z=49 HTTP/1.1
```

Comment: Thank you ! This is useful. I didn't try it yet, but this is definitely a step forward. I'll let you know what are the results when I'll try. Too bad that we need to use a small hack and that it does not exist any official way to end a session...

Answer (score 0):

In GoogleAnalytics v2 they have new ways to start/stop the session.

I have not seen your code of `mTracker.setStartSession(true)` and `mTracker.setStartSession(false)` used before.

Now, if you don't want to use the EasyTracker methods you can start a new session by the following:
`mTracker.startNewSession("UA-xxxxxxx-x", 20, this);`

With the first input being
 `(String uniqueGoogleAnalyticsKey, int autoDispatchTimer, Context this)`

To stop it:
`tracker.stopSession();`

Comment: Hi.If you go at this page : https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v2/sessions which clearly suggest that its the v2 doc, you'll see at the section "Manual session management" that they use 'myTracker.setStartSession(true);' My question was : can we use 'myTracker.setStartSession(false)' as what you suggest 'myTracker.stopSession()' does not seem to exist.

Comment: @p4u144, I think Grant was referring to the GA V1 (legacy) and not the current V2 beta.  Although, I'm also interested in finding a solution to your question.  V1's docs are here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/devguide

Comment: @Grant  I believe EasyTracker is the recommended way of working with Google Analytics

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky yes EasyTracker is definitely the recommended way. However, the question asks for a way to not use EasyTracker.