# Android Google Analytics v2 manually manage session without using EasyTracker

Tags: android, session, google-analytics, session-timeout, google-analytics-api

**I need to start and to stop a session at a specific hour.**
In [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v2/sessions) I have found only that I can start a new session :

```
// Called after a user successfully signs in to your app.
private void onSignIn() {
  ... // The rest of your onSignIn() code.
  myTracker.setStartSession(true); // Where myTracker is an instance of Tracker.
  myTracker.sendEvent("app_flow", "sign_in", "", null); // First activity of new session.
}
```

But I have no methods in API to stop the session or to change the session time out.
I already tried to set `ga_sessionTimeout` to 1 day but it didn't worked,
after ~8 minutes the session was closed even when the activity was still on the screen.I saw it on my Google Analytics dashboard's real-time overview.

Other ideas will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> By default, Google Analytics will group hits that are received within
>   **30 minutes** of one another into the same session.

My goal was to keep the session alive till some event happen,
therefore I decided to implement Heartbeat mechanism.
That will send event every X minutes to keep the session alive.

It solved my problem.

P.S. : I discovered another [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9448007/does-google-analytics-have-a-heartbeat-function-for-long-running-web-applicati) with same solution.

Comment: That's an interesting approach to keeping the sessions alive.  I needed something that would let me stop a session at a particular time as well (less than 30 minutes though).  I put my solution here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13601916/how-to-stop-a-session-in-google-mobile-analytics-v2-for-android-without-easytrac

Comment: It says 30 seconds "A default implementation has a session timeout period of 30 seconds. You can change the timeout period by modifying ga_sessionTimeout parameter in your analytics.xml file:..." I am confused.